# Python fractal tree using SVG

Tags: python, svg, fractals

I made a simple program to generate fractal tree using PATH object of SVG. Any suggestions?

```
import math
from random import randint

# const - upper limit for randint
s = 10

"""Simple fractal tree using SVG and recursion.

Usage:
    Create Root object bt Branch(x1=400, y1=800, x2=400, y2=600, color=60, size=35)
    x1, y1, x2, y2 - start points of root

    Generate Tree Tree(lenght=200, angle=-20, depth=9, x1=400, y1=600, size=35, color=60, outlist=resutlist)

    lenght - lenght of start branch
    angle - start angle of branch
    depth - number of tree level
    x1, y1 - start point of branch
"""


class Branch():
    """Class represents a single branch."""
    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2, color, size):
        """Assigning  values."""
        self.x1 = x1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y1 = y1
        self.y2 = y2
        self.color = color
        self.size = size

    def __str__(self):
        """Return path SVG object with points, color and stroke of branch."""
        return '<path d="M {x1} {y1} L {x2} {y2}" stroke="rgb(100,{c},0)" stroke-width="{w}"/>\n'.format(
            x1=self.x1,
            y1=self.y1,
            x2=self.x2,
            y2=self.y2,
            w=self.size,
            c=self.color
        )

    def __repr__(self):
        """Return text represent object."""
        return self.__str__()


class Tree():
    """
    Class represents Tree.

    Tree is composed of Branch object.
    """
    def __init__(self, lenght, angle, depth, x1, y1, size, color, outlist):
        """Main point of start generation."""
        self.branches = self.drawbranch(lenght, angle, depth, x1, y1, size, color, outlist)

    def drawbranch(self, lenght, angle, depth, x1, y1, size, color, outlist):
        """Recursive function for generate three Branch object per iteration."""
        # if depth > 0
        if depth:
            # X value of second point
            x2 = x1 + lenght * math.cos(math.radians(angle))
            # Y value of second point
            y2 = y1 + lenght * math.sin(math.radians(angle))

            # modify lenght of single branch
            lenght = float(2.0 / 3.0 * lenght)
            # modify size of single branch
            size = float(2.0 / 3.0 * size) + 1
            # modify color of single branch
            color += 6

            # X value of B point
            bx = x1
            # Y value of B point
            by = y2

            # X value of C point
            cx = -x2 + 2 * x1
            # Y value of C point
            cy = y2

            # Create A point
            b1 = Branch(x1, y1, x2, y2, color, size)
            # Add to list
            outlist.append(str(b1))
            # Call drawbranch function (recursion)
            self.drawbranch(lenght, angle + randint(-10, s), depth - 1, x2, y2, size, color, outlist)

            # Create B point
            b2 = Branch(x1, y1, bx, by, color, size)
            # Add to list
            outlist.append(str(b2))
            # Calculate new angle
            nangle = angle + randint(-1, 0) * randint(1, s)
            # Call drawbranch function (recursion)
            self.drawbranch(lenght, nangle, depth - 1, bx, by, size, color, outlist)

            # Create C point
            b3 = Branch(x1, y1, cx, cy, color, size)
            # Add to list
            outlist.append(str(b3))
            # Calculate new angle
            nangle = angle + randint(0, 1) * randint(1, s)
            # Call drawbranch function (recursion)
            self.drawbranch(lenght, nangle, depth - 1, cx, cy, size, color, outlist)

        # Return list of branches
        return outlist

    def write_svg(self, output='drzewko.svg'):
        """Function that write all branches to SVG file."""
        with open(output, 'w') as outfile:
            # Write SVG declaration
            outfile.write('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 800 800" version="1.1">\n')
            # Map to str all branches and write it into file
            outfile.writelines(map(str, self.branches))
            # End of SVG file
            outfile.write('</svg>\n')


print "Start generating, please wait.."
# Create empty list
resutlist = []
# Create root of Tree and add to list
resutlist.append(Branch(x1=400, y1=800, x2=400, y2=600, color=60, size=35))

# Call Tree object
t = Tree(lenght=200, angle=-20, depth=9, x1=400, y1=600, size=35, color=60, outlist=resutlist)
# After generate tree save to file
t.write_svg()

print "Done, check SVG file"
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: The generated tree doesn't look very natural. Needs some more randomness probably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting problem thanks for sharing.

I have refactored your code and it is included in it entirety below.  The most significant change made was to introduce a `Point` class, to encapsulate `(x, y)` pairs, and to provide a bit of syntactic sugar to math on same.

**Make `Point` as class:**

So this code:

```
# X value of C point
cx = -x2 + 2 * x1
# Y value of C point
cy = y2
```

can become:

```
c = Point(-p2.x + 2 * p1.x, p2.y)
```

via a `namedtuple` that provides an immutable datastructure whose attributes can be accessed with things like `p2.x`.

**Comments:**

I removed many of your comments.  In several of these cases, I renamed a variable to include the information that was present in the comment.

**Use object attributes**

Before the edits, the variable `branches` was being passed recursively, but it was eventually assigned as an attribute of the `Tree` class.  So the new code just starts there, and `branches` is an attribute of the class from the beginning.

**Type cast to float?**

In general you do not need to cast floats to floats.  So something like:

```
 branch_length = float(2.0 / 3.0 * length)
```

can just be:

```
 branch_length = 2.0 / 3.0 * length
```

since `2.0` is already a float.

**Complete Code:**

```
import math
from random import randint
from collections import namedtuple

# const - upper limit for randint
s = 10


class Point(namedtuple('Point', 'x y')):

    def __str__(self):
        return'{} {}'.format(self.x, self.y)

    def __add__(self, other):
        assert isinstance(other, Point)
        return Point(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return Point(self.x * other, self.y * other)

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return self.__mul__(other)


class Branch(namedtuple('Branch', 'p1 p2 color size')):

    def __str__(self):
        """Path SVG object with points, color and stroke of branch."""
        return ('<path d="M {p1} L {p2}" '
                'stroke="rgb(100,{c},0)" stroke-width="{w}"/>\n'.
                format(p1=self.p1, p2=self.p2, w=self.size, c=self.color))

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()


class Tree(object):

    def __init__(self, length, angle, depth, point, size, color, outlist):
        """Main point of start generation."""
        self.branches = outlist
        self.draw_branches(length, angle, depth, point, size, color)

    def draw_branches(self, length, angle, depth, p1, size, color):
        """ Recursively generate three Branch objects per iteration."""
        if depth <= 0:
            return

        p2 = p1 + length * Point(
            math.cos(math.radians(angle)),
            math.sin(math.radians(angle))
        )

        # set some new characteristics for the next level
        branch_length = 2.0 / 3.0 * length
        branch_size = 2.0 / 3.0 * size + 1
        color += 6

        # Calculate new angle and recurse
        self.branches.append(Branch(p1, p2, color, branch_size))
        nangle = angle + randint(-10, s)
        self.draw_branches(branch_length, nangle, depth - 1,
                           p2, branch_size, color)

        # Calculate new angle and recurse
        b = Point(p1.x, p2.y)
        self.branches.append(Branch(p1, b, color, branch_size))
        nangle = angle + randint(-1, 0) * randint(1, s)
        self.draw_branches(branch_length, nangle, depth - 1,
                           b, branch_size, color)

        # Calculate new angle and recurse
        c = Point(-p2.x + 2 * p1.x, p2.y)
        self.branches.append(Branch(p1, c, color, branch_size))
        nangle = angle + randint(0, 1) * randint(1, s)
        self.draw_branches(branch_length, nangle, depth - 1,
                           c, branch_size, color)

    def write_svg(self, output='drzewko.svg'):
        with open(output, 'w') as outfile:
            outfile.write('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" '
                          'viewBox="0 0 800 800" version="1.1">\n')
            outfile.writelines(map(str, self.branches))
            outfile.write('</svg>\n')


print("Start generating, please wait..")

# a starting point
resultlist = [Branch(Point(400, 800), Point(400, 600), color=60, size=35)]

# Build and save the tree as an svg
t = Tree(length=200, angle=-20, depth=9, point=Point(400, 600),
         size=35, color=60, outlist=resultlist)
t.write_svg()

print("Done, check SVG file")
```